# ATI RV370 Graphics problems with Ubuntu installation on Dell Dimension 9100 desktop

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 18.04, graphics, amd-graphics

My current install is Ubuntu 18.04. I've also tried 14.04 and 16.04 versions and still have the same issues:

Screen artifacts, lagging, freezing, windows break and fragment and stick over each other even after closing them. 
My graphics card is ATI Radeon X300 SE HyperMemory

A very strange thing happens when I ran glxgears from terminal: Everything gets fixed all of a sudden...!? 
It's not perfect and when I drag the windows there's still some image echo but it's a far cry from freezing and artifacts hiding the screen.

What is enabled, or disabled, when glxgears runs?
I'm letting it run while I start GIMP and Inkskape sessions and everything runs beautifully smooth...

Is there any script that I can use, to replicate what glxgears does, and permanently fix the graphics issues in my ubuntu install?

Or better yet, is there any kernel driver fix, or driver version, that I can install to fix my graphics issues?